# Why can't I add keywords to a specific category?

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, taxonomy, keyword

I've created a category with several keywords and subkeywords. When I try to add a sub keyword to a specific keyword, it works for only the first 3...:
[image]

As you can see the "new" option in the context menu doesn't even show up.
All the keywords are "Normal". I can't find any reason for this behavior. I am a system Administrator, by the way, so no permissions issues here.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you try using the New button from the Ribbon toolbar? IIRC it was a UI bug with 2013sp1.

Comment: I think it`s support 3 level of keyword creations. please check with SDL support.

Comment: Do you have the option to add new keywords if you either go up to the parent keyword and click refresh on it, or f5 and and reload the entire browser? I have encountered a bug where this happens until you refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time, clearing the cache and closing/opening the browser, the ui started to behave normally again. If it occurs again, I will re-open the question. I believe that the workaround (in case this happens again) is to do what Nick recommends and use the ribbon button. It seems to be a bug indeed in the UI, but it is not happening anymore.

Comment: it`s browser cache issue.

Comment: yes....Even I faced similar issue earlier.